# Is it possible to order by any column given a stored procedure parameter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I was looking into sorting tables by a column designated given some input, and from what I've found, there is no easy way to do this. The best I've found is a switch statement:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
FROM Table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBY = 'Column1' THEN Column1
              WHEN @OrderBY = 'Column2' THEN Column2
              WHEN @OrderBY = 'Column3' THEN Column3
              WHEN @OrderBY = 'Column4' THEN Column4
```

Is it possible to do this without having a `CASE` statement like that? If the table gets bigger and more columns need to be sorted by, this could become messy.

The only way I've been able to do this is by just concatenating a big SQL string, which sort of defeats the advantages of Stored Procedures, and makes the SQL hard to write and maintain.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149380/dynamic-sorting-within-sql-stored-procedures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. As you have implemented above
2. Or generate dynamic sql and execute
   using `sp_executesql`

Comment: Never generate dynamic SQL inside or outside stored procedure, you'll loose performance because the optimized cannot cache the statements

Comment: It is not true. My colleague discovers, that in some cases is generated code actually FASTER than using @variables in stored procedure. We really don't know why, but it is true. MSSQL2000, 80GB database, 300+ connections, 10~100 sql statements/sec, complex stored procedures

Comment: With sp_executesql, SQL Server stores the execution plan for your statement. If you then call sp_executesql with the same query but with different parameters, the execution plan will be reused. Using "exec" instead no plan is kept, you loose performance.

Comment: The main problem with sp_executesql is the vulnerability to SQL Injection

Comment: Why would you generate dynamic SQL, with all the associated risks, when you can use a CASE in the ORDER BY clause? BTW, I didn't realize you could do decisions in the ORDER BY - that's a nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

I generally convert the stored procedure to a function that returns a table ( so you can select FROM it ... and add the dynamic order by columns to it in the application code:

```
Select
    *
From
   myTableFUnction()
Order by
   1, 2, 3, 6  <-- defined by application code in the SQL for the query
```

Ron

Comment: Also, Functions can not contain certain (non-deterministic) operators.

Answer (score 1):

The RANK feature of SQL Server and Oracle can improve performance and makes the code a little cleaner:

SQL:

```
DECLARE @column varchar(10)

SET @column = 'D'

SELECT *
FROM Collection.Account AS A
ORDER BY 
      CASE 
            WHEN @column = 'A' THEN (RANK() OVER(ORDER BY A.Code ASC))
            WHEN @column = 'D' THEN (RANK() OVER(ORDER BY A.Code DESC))
      END
```

Answer (score 1):

You already write the correct syntax:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
FROM SOME_TABLE
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

try it

Answer (score -2):

In this case, unless you have an extremely large dataset and you need to leverage the power of the database server (thin client, weak client machine, etc), it is best to sort within the client.

Comment: Why would this be the case exactly?