# Multiple column sorting in Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid, grid

Hi I want to Sort Multiple column In a gridview like shown here 
[Hierarchical (Multi-column) Sorting for the .net GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429261/hierarchical-multi-column-sorting-for-the-net-gridview)

I did my home work 
My aspx looks like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Multiple sorting with Gridview</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
            AllowSorting="true" onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" style="margin-right: 541px" 
            Width="873px">
        </asp:GridView>
        <p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSortExpression" /></p>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

In my Aspx.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private ListDictionary m_ldSortExpression;
    private ListDictionary SortExpressions
    {
        get
        {
            m_ldSortExpression = (ListDictionary)ViewState["SortExpressions"];
            if (m_ldSortExpression == null)
            {
                m_ldSortExpression = new ListDictionary();
            }
            return m_ldSortExpression;
        }
        set { ViewState["SortExpressions"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }

    public void BindData()
    {
        // Usually you would get the data from the database.
        // To simplify the code, I will just fill a datatable with some standard data.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
        dt.Columns.Add("Age");
        dt.Columns.Add("Position");

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
            "1",
            "2",
            28,
            "5"
        });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
            "2",
            "8",
            31,
            "2"
        });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
            "2",
            "4",
            31,
            "4"
        });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
            "3",
            "7",
            37,
            "3"
        });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
            "4",
            "4",
            40,
            "1"
        });

        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        // use a stringbuilder to hold the sortexpression for the dataview
        StringBuilder sbSortExpression = new StringBuilder();
        if (SortExpressions.Count > 0)
        {
            string[] myKeys = new string[SortExpressions.Count + 1];
            SortExpressions.Keys.CopyTo(myKeys, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i <= SortExpressions.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                sbSortExpression.Append(myKeys[i]);
                sbSortExpression.Append(" ");
                sbSortExpression.Append(SortExpressions[myKeys[i]]);
                if (i != SortExpressions.Count - 1)
                {
                    sbSortExpression.Append(", ");
                }

            }
            lblSortExpression.Text = sbSortExpression.ToString();

            // usually we would send that sort-expression now to SQL via some stored-procedure
            dv.Sort = sbSortExpression.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lblSortExpression.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dv;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        PositionGlyph(GridView1, dv.Sort.ToString(), dt);


    }

    private void PositionGlyph(GridView GridView1, string p,DataTable dt)
    {
        if ((GridView1.Rows.Count == 0) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)))
            return;

        Image glyph = new Image();
        glyph.EnableTheming = false;

        string[] words = p.Split(',');

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            string[] SortType = word.Split(' ');
            if (SortType[SortType.Length - 1] == SortOrder.Ascending.ToString().Substring(0, 3).ToUpper())
                glyph.ImageUrl = "~/Images/down_arrow.png";

            else
                glyph.ImageUrl = "~/Images/up_arrow.png";

            int columnindex = dt.Columns[SortType[SortType.Length - 2].ToString()].Ordinal;
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[columnindex].Controls.Add(glyph);
            //for (int x = 0; x < dt.Columns.Count; x++)
            //{
            //    if (SortType[SortType.Length - 2].ToString()== dt.Columns[x].ColumnName)
            //    {
            //        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[x].Controls.Add(glyph);
            //        break;
            //    }
            //}

        }

    }

    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        m_ldSortExpression = SortExpressions;

        if (!m_ldSortExpression.Contains(e.SortExpression))
        {
            m_ldSortExpression.Add(e.SortExpression, e.SortDirection.ToString().Replace("Ascending", "ASC").Replace("Descending", "DESC"));
        }
        else
        {
            // Get sort direction
            string strSortDirection = m_ldSortExpression[e.SortExpression].ToString();
            // Was it ascending?
            if (strSortDirection == "ASC")
            {
                // Yes, so sort in desc
                m_ldSortExpression[e.SortExpression] = "DESC";
            }
            else if (strSortDirection == "DESC")
            {
                // it is descending
                // remove the sort order
                m_ldSortExpression.Remove(e.SortExpression);
            }
        }

        SortExpressions = m_ldSortExpression;
        BindData();
    }
    public _Default()
    {
        Load += Page_Load;
    }

}
```

Everything is working fine even multiple sorting but sort arrow in column header is not showing properly.I think issue is in PositionGlyph Method.Asc or Desc arrow is showing only for last clicked header.I want to show sort direction for all the columns.Please help me on the same

Comment: For the sake of anyone who wants to use this technique in an application, I want to note that the ListDictionary type is a poor choice for this purpose. It does not guarantee the keys to appear in any particular order, and sorting on FirstName then LastName is very different from sorting on LastName then FirstName. An OrderedDictionary would be a better choice.

Comment: @Martin what would you use for the key in the Ordered dictionary to make this work like the OP wants? Certainly not the Name of the column or the SortExpression.

Comment: Yes, you use the column name, just as Rahul shows. Mind you, that's as distinct from the column header text -- it does need to be a unique ID. This code works fine as written, you just swap every occurance of "ListDictionary" for "OrderedDictionary" to make sure it retains the correct ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Use This:

```
DataView m_DataView = new DataView(dt);
m_DataView.Sort =ColumnName1 + " ASC, " + ColumnName2 + " ASC, " + ColumnName3 + " ASC";
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Ansari Sorting is working fine just want to show the up and down arrow for column headers in all columns

Answer (score 0):

you can show the arrow for sorting behavior of a gridview column in the RowCreated event something like this i usually do it this way

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (tc.HasControls())
            {
                // search for the header link
                LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)tc.Controls[0];
                if (lnk != null && GridView1.SortExpression == lnk.CommandArgument)
                {
                    // inizialize a new image
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    // setting the dynamically URL of the image
                    img.ImageUrl = "~/img/ico_" + (GridView1.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "asc" : "desc") + ".gif";
                    // adding a space and the image to the header link
                    tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" "));
                    tc.Controls.Add(img);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it also toggles the image on ascending and descending sort orders of column

What the code actually do is it loops through the GridView Header to search a LinkButton (the Framework creates it only if the SortExpression property is set). Then, if the found LinkButton is the sorted field, then it shows the image to the output, that's all

Please see this [sample](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-show-up-and-down-arrows-during.html)

Comment: Ramesh Thanks for your reply .I have seen your sample. Sorting is working fine for above code snippet just to show the sort direction .I mean up and down arrow for all the columns