# SQL Server dynamic ORDER BY with mixed datatypes: is this a good idea?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have stored procedure that returns results sorted dynamically. The parent folder (this is for content management) has a RankTypeID field that allows sorting by Rank (0), Start Date in ascending order (1), Start Date in descending order (2), and document title (3)

Rank is an integer, date is smalldatetime, and title is a nvarchar.

...

```
ORDER BY
    Case Parent.RankTypeID
      When 0 Then dbo.Folders.Rank
      When 1 Then Cast(dbo.Documents.SortableDateStart As bigint)
      When 2 Then (1 - Cast(dbo.Documents.SortableDateStart As bigint))
      When 3 Then Cast(dbo.Documents.Title as sql_variant)
    End
```

I set up the SortableDateStart as a computed column to take a DateStart smalldatetime column and convert it into a bigit for sorting. It takes an ISO8601 date (designed for xml usage, and also handy for sorting) and replaces the T, :, and -

```
(replace(replace(replace(CONVERT([varchar](16),[DateStart],(126)),'T',''),'-',''),':',''))
```

This is kind of ugly. Is there a better way to do this? I'm also open to better ways of handling this dynamic sorting.

**Edit: Test Data Setup**

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
[Rank] int,
[Title] nvarchar(100),
[DateStart] datetime
)

INSERT into @Temp
SELECT 1, 'title1', '1/1/2010 10:01:00AM'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'atitle1', '1/1/2010 10:03:00AM'
UNION
SELECT 3, 'title1', '1/1/2010 10:10:00AM'
UNION
SELECT 4, 'btitle1', '1/1/2010 10:04:00AM'
UNION
SELECT 10, 'title1', '1/1/2010 10:07:00AM'
UNION
SELECT 11, 'dtitle1', '1/1/2010 10:09:00AM'
UNION
SELECT 12, 'ctitle1', '1/1/2010 10:00:01AM'
UNION
SELECT 13, 'title1', '1/1/2010 10:10:00AM'

DECLARE @RankTypeID tinyint
--SET @RankTypeID = 0 -- rank
--SET @RankTypeID = 1 -- date start asc
SET @RankTypeID = 2 -- date start desc
--SET @RankTypeID = 3 -- title

SELECT 
    [Rank],
    [DateStart],
    [Title]
FROM
    @Temp
ORDER BY
    Case @RankTypeID
      When 0 Then [Rank]
      When 1 Then Cast([DateStart] As sql_variant)
      When 3 Then [Title]
      else null
    End,      
    Case @RankTypeID
      When 2 Then Cast([DateStart] As sql_variant)
    End DESC
```

Comment: @Denis - no kidding, that's why I'm asking!

Comment: Give us a bigger picture of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Denis - sure, added some more details. not sure what else I can tell you - ask away!

Comment: This is like the worst kinds of mess that people create by being so rigid about using stored procedures instead of prepared statements locked up a proper DAL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this

```
ORDER BY
    Case Parent.RankTypeID
      When 0 Then dbo.Folders.Rank
      When 1 Then dbo.Documents.DateStart
      When 3 Then Cast(dbo.Documents.Title as sql_variant)
      else null
    End,      
    case Parent.RankTypeID
      when 2 Then dbo.Documents.DateStart
    end desc
```

**Update.**

No, you don't need to cast anything. Here's a full solution for your test data.

```
order by 
case @RankTypeID when 0 then [Rank] else null end,      
case @RankTypeID when 1 then [DateStart] else null end,
case @RankTypeID when 2 then [DateStart] else null end desc,
case @RankTypeID when 3 then [Title] else null end
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Do you have some test data that you're tried this against?

Comment: You set me on the right path - but you have to cast the date as a sql_variant because it can't be casted automatically like varchar/int. Update your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: That's right, you can process those columns separately using this multiple sorting expressions technique. As you can see, I had to deal with your situation theoretically and not practically.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look at the execution plan and see what works better.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to decouple the sort value and the actual ORDER BY

```
SELECT
   col1, col2, ...
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      col1, col2, ...,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rank) AS RankASC,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateStart) AS DateStartASC,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Title) AS TitleASC
   FROM
      MyTable
   ) foo
ORDER BY
    Case foo.RankTypeID
      When 0 Then foo.RankAsc
      When 1 Then foo.DateStartAsc
      When 2 Then -1 * foo.DateStartAsc
      When 3 Then foo.TitleAsc
      --else null needed?
    End
```

If you want to define @SortOrder (or as a column) as 1 = ASC, -1 = DESC then you can do this

```
SELECT
   col1, col2, ...
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      col1, col2, ...,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rank) AS RankOrder,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateStart) AS DateStartOrder,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Title) AS TitleOrder
   FROM
      MyTable
   ) foo
ORDER BY
    @SortOrder *
      Case foo.RankTypeID
        When 0 Then foo.RankOrder
        When 1 Then foo.DateStartOrder
        When 3 Then foo.TitleOrder
      End
```

Comment: How would this perform? Also, my query is fairly complicated - multiple CTEs and grouping.

Comment: probably no worse than CASTing. You can also remove the ORDER BY CASE, if you push some logic deeper to zero each ROW_NUMBER *not* to be sorted. Then your order by becomes RankOrder, DateStartOrder, TitleOrder
 which will help too. Personally I don't like CASE in ORDER BY :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input. If my query wasn't so complicated I'd give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Another working complete solution sample is given below

```
--TEST DATA
DECLARE @MYTable TABLE (EmpID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(10) , JoinDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES (1,'E1','1/1/2001');
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES (2,'E2','2/2/2002');
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES (3,'E3','5/5/2001');

--INPUT Parameters
DECLARE @SortParam VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SortParam = 'JoinDate'

DECLARE @SortDirection VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SortDirection = 'DESC'


--@RankTypeID Variable
DECLARE @RankTypeID  INT

--EMPNAME
IF (@SortParam = 'EmpName' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC')
BEGIN 
    SET @RankTypeID = 1 
END

IF (@SortParam = 'EmpName' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC')
BEGIN
    SET @RankTypeID = -1    
END

--EmpID
IF (@SortParam = 'EmpID' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC')
BEGIN 
    SET @RankTypeID = 2 
END

IF (@SortParam = 'EmpID' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC')
BEGIN
    SET @RankTypeID = -2
END

--JoinDate
IF (@SortParam = 'JoinDate' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC')
BEGIN 
    SET @RankTypeID = 3 
END

IF (@SortParam = 'JoinDate' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC')
BEGIN
    SET @RankTypeID = -3
END


-- SELECT
SELECT * 
FROM @MYTable M
ORDER BY 
        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN 1 then EmpName ELSE null end ASC,
        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN -1 then EmpName ELSE null end DESC,

        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN 2 then [EmpID] else null end ASC ,
        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN -2 then [EmpID] else null end DESC ,

        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN 3 then JoinDate else null end  ASC,
        CASE @RankTypeID WHEN -3 then JoinDate else null end  DESC


--END
```