# Complex mix of sorting, ordering, filtering SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, filtering

Basically I have to build a list of items from a SQL database however the user can choose to filter on any combination of 7 filters and can also choose a column to order by and also the order by direction.

As you can imagine this ends in a large number of different combinations to code for and the dataset is quite large so I'd like to avoid doing this in the application.

In my stored procedure so far I have tried:

- Building  a query string, although this is quite simple and easy to follow, it leaves the application open to SQL injection so I would rather avoid this.
- Using a set of `IF ELSE` statements to run proper parameterised SQL however this quickly becomes a huge tree and will be a nightmare to maintain.

I'm not the first person that has needed a solution like this and there must be a better way than the above?  Also as a side question is there a good way to do order by and order by direction in a parameterised way, besides doing lots of `IF`s?

Comment: If you can reduce the filters to `and (fld1 = @filter1 or @filter1 is null)` you should read this http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filtering, use the [`COELSCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to filter by any combination of conditions. In your stored procedure there would be a list of all parameters that the user would search for, then in the your query will be something like:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM YourTable t
 WHERE 1 = 1
 AND t.FirstColumn = COALESCE(@FirstColumnParam, t.FirstColumn)
 AND t.SecodndColumn = COALESCE(@SecondColumnParam, t.SecondColumn) 
 ....
```

If any of the parameters is null, then the condition is skipped. and for `1=1` that's in case there is no filter coditions is passed to your query.

For Ordering: you can use the `CASE` statement to order by any choosen column:

```
ORDER BY ( CASE WHEN @OrderByParam = 1 Then FirstColumn ELSE .... END)
```

Comment: Will the optimizer see this is a SARG and use indexes if you use the COALESCE function?

Comment: @buckley, No, I think it will create indexes in case It is written the way you wrote `AND (FirstColumn = @FirstColumnParam OR @FirstColumnParam Is NULL)`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal thanks very much, works a treat!  There are so many nice SQL keywords that I find out about every now and then like this!

Comment: The COALESCE pattern will fail for nullable columns, because NULL does not equal NULL. Also, in some situations ISNULL performs much better than COALESCE, even though they appear equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

> Building a query string, although this is quite simple and easy to
>   follow, it leaves the application open to SQL injection so I would
>   rather avoid this.

Not if you use **sp_executesql** and pass your parameters as arguments tot that sproc. Since you give your data as parameters there will be no sql injection

http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/04/03/dynamic-sql-and-sql-injection/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx

> I've also tried using a set of IF ELSE statements to run proper
>   parameterised SQL however this quickly becomes a huge tree and will be
>   a nightmare to maintain.

Agree if you use IF ELSE but there is also a pattern called **catch all queries**

```
WHERE (ProductID = @Product Or @Product IS NULL)
AND (ReferenceOrderID = @OrderID OR @OrderID Is NULL)
...
```

More info here  http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Be sure to specify OPTION (RECOMPILE) at the end since otherwise your queries can suffer for what is called as **parameter sniffing**

```
Also as a side question is there a good way to do order by and order by direction in a parameterised way, besides doing lots of IFs?
```

Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Sorting within SQL Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149380/dynamic-sorting-within-sql-stored-procedures)

In the end you can with sp_executesql or catch all queries (this is a common problem with these 2 tried solutions). I usualy prefere catch all queries but don't forget to specify option (recompile).

Comment: You cannot pass a `where` clause as argument to `sp_executesql`.  And if you build the SQL argument to `sp_executesql` dynamically, that is of course open for SQL injection.,

Comment: @Andomar I clarified the answer that you have to pass them as arguments to the sproc. I would just go for a catch all + option recompile, that would also simplify the dynamic ordering